# MS-SQL Error sqlcmd library when emailing results as CSV

Tags: sql-server

I want to run a query and export my results as a CSV so the requesting department can open and filter as they please.

This is my code:

```
EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail
@profile_name = 'EpdmAdmin',
@recipients=@MyEmail,
@subject='Test Email',
@query = @SqlQuery,
@attach_query_result_as_file=1,
@query_attachment_filename = 'Results.csv',
@query_result_separator = ','
```

I get the following error message:

> Error Message: Msg 22050, Level 16, State 1, Line 0 Failed to
>   initialize sqlcmd library with error number -2147467259.

Comment: sounds like security settings, and this would be better suited to dba.se

Answer (score 0, accepted):

answering my own question here. I believe it had to do with the way I used the @query. I had multiple joins and a long piece of code equal to the query var. When I changed this to be inserted into a table and simplified my query to be "Select * from MyTable" it worked! Thanks for the help